# Backstepping control of second order nonlinear system

Tags: control-theory, nonlinear-system, nonlinear-analysis, nonlinear-dynamics, adaptive-control

$\dot{x_{1}}=x_{2}^2-3\sin(x_{1})x_{2}$

$\dot{x_{2}}=x_{1}^3-3x_{2}\cos(x_{1})+u^{1/2}$

Question: Using the backstepping method and Lyapunov function, design the controller $u$ that will make the following system asymptotically stable.

For backstepping control, $x_{1}$ must be in this form;

$\dot{x_{1}}=f(x_{1})+g(x_{1})x_{2}$

then,

$e_{1}=x_{1}-x_{1}^d,\space \dot{e_{1}}=\dot{x_{1}}-\dot{x_{1}}^d$, where $e_{1}: error, \space x_{1}^d: desired\space x_{1}$

and Lyapunov function is $L_{1}=\frac{1}{2}e_{1}^2, \space \dot{L_{1}}=e_{1}\dot{e_{1}}$.
For asymptotically stability, $\dot{L_{1}}=-k_{1}e_{1}^2, k_{1}>0$.
Now we have a $x_{2}$ that extracted from $\dot{L_{1}}$ and this $x_{2}=x_{2}^d$ for $e_{2}=x_{2}-x_{2}^d$. Where, $\dot{L_{2}}=e_{2}\dot{e_{2}}^2$ and $\dot{L_{2}}=-k_{2}e_{2}^2, k_{2}>0$. Finally we can extract $u$ from $\dot{L_{2}}$.

But in this question $\dot{x_{1}}$ is not in form $\dot{x_{1}}=f(x_{1})+g(x_{1})x_{2}$. So how can I solve this question with backstepping control?

Comment: You might be able to get the system to fit the standard form by using a coordinate transformation. The sin and cos terms might suggest that this is in polar coordinates, however switching to cartesian coordinates does not seem to help much. Are you sure these are the correct equations?

Comment: yes, these are correct. now, for example, may i transform $x_{2}=r\cos(phi)$. if $r=1$ we can employ in unit circle. is it right? so if it is right, i think i can estimate that the system is aymptotically stable.

Comment: http://research.harkegard.se/slides/internsem_050127.pdf is a nice set of slides demonstrating this method and related ones. And indeed, the non-normalized form of the first equation seems to prevent a straight-forward application of the method. Could you just claim that there was a typo in the task and it should be $\dot x_1=x_1^2-3\sin(x_1)x_2$ and work with that equation in the system?

Comment: thanks for your answers. i would have expected the system to be that way but what i wrote is correct.